# YUI Changing data table depending on list selection

Tags: yui

Please advise, I want to make a drop down list that can filter a data table for example if you have data table for invoices and user can select from a drop down list that has invoice types 'debit credit .. etc' , so depend on this selection it should filter the data table using YUI.

Many Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This example is more complex than what you describe, but it's the same basic idea:  http://jafl.github.com/yui3-gallery/querybuilder/

Comment: Thank you John ,sure it can help :)